# Python ctypes TypeError for defined function

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a known function type definition of `wintypes.HANDLE, wintypes.LPVOID` with a return value of `wintypes.DWORD`.

Using `ctypes` I've defined the type and function and tried to make the call with a `handle` and `lpvoid` reference:

```
ftype = CFUNCTYPE(wintypes.HANDLE, wintypes.LPVOID, wintypes.DWORD)
function = ftype(address)

base = wintypes.LPVOID(0x0)
ptr = function(GetCurrentProcess(), byref(base))
```

However, when executing I receive an error:
`ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type`

Can someone please help me identify the problem?

What `type` should I be passing, if not the defined `lpvoid`?

Comment: Well, a `byref(base)` would be `void **`.  Wouldn't you just pass `base`?

Comment: Tried that too, same error message `argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type`

Comment: There are three arguments, you're only supplying 2.

Comment: Last argument is the return type

Comment: No, the FIRST argument is the return type.  Still, I admit i was wrong.

Comment: Arghhh interesting detail. This might actually be the source of the problem. Let me look into it..

Comment: Also, `base` is already an LPVOID, so passing `byref` would pass a `void**` not a `void*`.

Comment: And it should be `ftype = CFUNCTYPE(wintypes.DWORD, wintypes.HANDLE, wintypes.LPVOID)` as pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a minimal example.  I created a DLL with the function signature described and extracted the address to demo the Python code.

```c
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API
#endif

API DWORD function(HANDLE h, LPVOID pv) {
    printf("h=%p pv=%p\n", h, pv);
    return 1;
}
```

```py
from ctypes import *
from ctypes import wintypes

dll = CDLL('./test')
address = addressof(dll.function)

# return value is the FIRST parameter to CFUNCTYPE
ftype = CFUNCTYPE(wintypes.DWORD, wintypes.HANDLE, wintypes.LPVOID)

# ftype(address) doesn't expect an unwrapped C address, but a Python function,
# so I used from_address() instead.
function = ftype.from_address(address)

ret = function(0x123,None) # None can be used for a null pointer
print(ret)
```

Output:

```
h=0000000000000123 pv=0000000000000000
1
```